# How to return exact case insensitive matches and evaluate as true/false

Tags: javascript, regex

This is a *JavaScript* problem...

I am trying to return exact case insensitive matches. For example, if I enter `"yo"` in the input box, I want it to return as `true`, which it does in my current approach, but it will also return `true` for anything ending or starting with `"yo"` (i.e. `your`). I still want cases like `"Yo!"` and `"yo, what's up"` to return `true`.

I've tried `startsWith()` and `endsWith()`, but I'm not really sure where to go with this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <input type="text" id="input1">
  <button type="submit" onclick="myFunction()">Test</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var arr1 = [/hello/i, /\bhi/i, /\bhey/i, /yo/i];
      var b = document.getElementById("input1").value;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arr1.some(regexp => regexp.test(b));
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to get exact matches for words, as opposed to just a string.

Comment: Will `hello dude` be accepted as `true`, or do you want to accept `hello` word exact match only?

Comment: hello dude is fine being accepted as true, but I don't want helloxyz to be accepted as true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are in your way using `\b` [Word Boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), but you have an incorrect usage of they. If you read the docs, you need to wrap the `word` you want to match, by the `\b` metacharacter, like `\bhello\b`. Give a try to next example:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var arr1 = [/\bhello\b/i, /\bhi\b/i, /\bhey\b/i, /\byo\b/i];
  var b = document.getElementById("input1").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arr1.some(regexp => regexp.test(b));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input1">
<button type="submit" onclick="myFunction()">Test</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I didn't understand the proper use of the \b metacharacter as this wasn't covered in any of the material I've studied, but now I fully understand it.

Comment: @AnthonyAlexander I'm glad it helps you, please consider to accept the answer if useful to you.